# How to write condition in apache jmeter request

Tags: jmeter, jmx

[image]
By refering to the image above, I want to write condition  in http request like if debitccy5 have null value then this field should not be in the request. If only then have value then only it should be visible in the request. Please suggest how to write this in jmeter.

I tried if controller but didnt worked

Comment: Could you please post a better/clear pic of the image, very hard to understand the request body.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way of achieving this is building the request body in [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) using [Groovy language.](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Take a look at [JsonBuilder](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html) class.

Comment: Yes tried groovy but not wrking. Still its sendinh tge fieldname. I want like if value is null then field name should not go